# Site is inaccessible after updating plugin with new attribute/db column

Tags: plugin-development

I'm making some modifications to a custom plugin. I added a new attribute to one of the models and created a migration to add a new database column to hold that attribute. I updated the version number in my main plugin file and everything ran smoothly in my local environment. However in production I get "an unknown error occured" with no actual PHP errors or Craft errors being logged. This is after Craft tries to perform it's database updates (and tells me it went successfully).

Running Craft 2.6.2982

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `getSchemaVersion()` to my main plugin file and returning a schema version did the trick.

```
public function getSchemaVersion()
{
    return '0.0.4';
}
```